# How does the content provider uri work?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I've been researching ContentProviders for a while now and I'm still having trouble grasping how exactly the Uri works.

content://app_name/**path**/id

When a path is specified how does the table corresponding to that path gets accessed?
It seems like you would need to label the table with that path. Is it so?

Answer (score 2):

You are right google docs on this point are not very clear :

First : you must define an authority for a custom provider :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI

```
<provider
     android:name=".ProviderDemo"
     android:authorities="com.foo.android.providerdemo" />
```

Second : use this authority when you query a provider : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI

```
 //query all items
 getContentResolver().query("content://com.foo.android.providerdemo/",...)

 //query a single item
 getContentResolver().query("content://com.foo.android.providerdemo/idOfItem>",...)

 //query a view
 getContentResolver().query("content://com.foo.android.providerdemo/<idOfView>/",...)
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you choose which action to take for an incoming content URI, the provider API includes the convenience class [UriMatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html), which maps content URI "patterns" to integer values. You can use the integer values in a switch statement that chooses the desired action for the content URI or URIs that match a particular pattern.

Answer (score 0):

My confusion came from a lack of SQLite knowledge. I was unaware that a database holds many tables and not just 1 table. Now I realize that the authority of the Uri must take you to the database and then the path will take you to the correct table.